# Why didn't show single byte zero "0" in email sent by cake email funtion

Tags: cakephp

My project is using cakephp2.5.7.

I send mail using SMTP transport. Mail sending is user has to fill in contact form and the main problem is showing data from textfield. Mail is successfully sent but a single zero is not show in email content, e.g. user can fill like this...

```
0 is<br/>
0<br/>
0<br/>
0<br/>
0 not show<br/>
```

but in email it only shows

```
0 is<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
0 not show<br/>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! I don't quite understand the question. What is "single byte zero"? You mean the letter `0`? Or the first byte? `0 is 0 0 0 0 is` - what does that mean? Also read this very good [introduction](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks for your comment.Single byte zero means letter zero "0".Now I updated my question.please check and help.

Comment: It is why? I think it's deal with Encoding of Cake Email->send() function.Please help???

Comment: Does it show up if you add some text around or before it? If the first and last 0 is showing up, it's unlikely to be anything to do with the encoding. Try replacing your dynamic data with static content (type in 0 manually there) and then go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the following code in `CakeEmail`

```
if (empty($line)) {
    $formatted[] = '';
    continue;
}
```

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.5.6/lib/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php#L1359-L1362**

Until this is fixed (**update:** fixed with [**#5202**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/5202)) there's not much you can do other than for example appending or prepending data to the lines that would evaluate as empty, or extending the `CakeEmail` class and ovewrriding `CakeEmail::_wrap()` with a fix.

A quick fix (without knowing about possible side effects) would be

```
if (empty($line) && $line != '0') {
    $formatted[] = '';
    continue;
}
```